# Ruby Yield on Block with Return Statement is Inconsistent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, block, yield

I'm trying to understand how ruby handles yields and return statements and noticed that sometimes, a yield on a block with a return statement is illegal but sometimes works.  I have the following example that I'm struggling with:

```
def foo
  yield
end

def bar
  foo do
    return 'asdf'
  end
end
```

Now in the above case, I know that the following will fail:

```
foo do
  return 'asdf'
end

> LocalJumpError: unexpected return
```

But the following will work (though it will return nil and not 'asdf'):

```
bar
=> nil
```

My question is why would what appears to be similar pieces of code react so differently?  Is it because the return block needs a method context to run in?  An even more subtle situation is the following

```
def baz
  yield
  puts 'Hi'
end

def bif
  baz do
    return 'asdf'
  end
end

bif
=> nil
```

The "puts 'Hi'" after the yield doesn't get run at all, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: search lambdas vs procs

Comment: In your `foo` example, the first one does a `return` without being inside a method or function. The second one, inside `bar` has a valid `return` since it's inside a method. In the `bif` case, the `return` is executed before the `puts` is. So the `puts` never occurs. It's as if `baz` did a `return` then did `puts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby Proc can't have a return statement. The return statements that seemed to work actually belong to the method(def...end).

A good article about it:
http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/

Comment: That link is actually pretty nice.  To summarize in my current situation:
The Proc being executed with a return DOES need to have a context to return to, which is based on where it was declared.  In addition, the "block" notation in ruby generates a Proc, which halts execution on return.  This is different than a lambda, which would continue.